# Symmetry of the domain?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

For the tiple integral 
$$\iiint_D (z^2+z) \,dx\,dy\,dz$$
over the domain $D:x^2+y^2+z^2\leq4,\quad z^2\leq x^2+y^2$

The textbook states that by symmetry of the domain the integral simplifies to
$$\iiint_D z^2 \,dx\,dy\,dz.$$
How exactly do they arrive at that conclusion?

Comment: The domain is symmetric about z, so the odd contribution cancels

Comment: Thanks for the reply. What exactly do you mean by the odd contribution cancels? What is the odd contribution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The domain is symmetric about $z$, and the function $f(x,y,z)=z$ is odd, meaning that
$$
f(x,y,-z)=-f(x,y,z)=-z
$$
Therefore 
$$
\iiint_D z \; dV = 0
$$

To understand why this happens, consider the $1$ dimensional case: do you see why 
$$
\int_{-a}^{a} x\; dx = 0 \; ?
$$

Comment: Thanks I think I get it: In your last example the area from 0 to a and from -a to zero cancel each other out?

Comment: Yes that is exactly it! @Matthew Leingang explains it well in the other answer ;)

Answer (score 3):

This is because 
$$
    \iiint_D z\,dV = 0
$$
Why is that? If $(a,b,c)$ is in $D$, then so is $(a,b,-c)$ (both inequalities have $z^2$ in them).  So each point $P$ in $D$ has a mirror-image point $P'$ on the opposite side of the $xy$-plane.  If $f(x,y,z) = z$, then $f(P') = -f(P)$.  Accumulating all the points $P$ above the $xy$-plane, their $f$-values cancel in pairs with their corresponding points $P'$.